# Matrix multiplication based question

Tags: matrices

Prove that $M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}^5\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^{10}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}^5=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$

---

$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}^5=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}$
$=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{16} & \frac{-1}{32}  \\
    \frac{1}{16} & \frac{5}{32}  \end{bmatrix}$
Similarly,$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^{10}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$
$=\begin{bmatrix}
    23 & 11  \\
    -22 & 34  \end{bmatrix}$
$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{16} & \frac{-1}{32}  \\
    \frac{1}{16} & \frac{5}{32}  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    23 & 11  \\
    -22 & 34  \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{3}{16} & \frac{-1}{32}  \\
    \frac{1}{16} & \frac{5}{32}  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$

---

I want to ask is there any method or formula available by which such long calculations can be avoided?
$M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}^5\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^{10}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \frac{1}{2}  \\
    -1 & \frac{1}{2}  \end{bmatrix}^5=(\frac{1}{2})^5\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    -2 & 1  \end{bmatrix}^5\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    2 & 0  \end{bmatrix}^{10}(\frac{1}{2})^5\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    -2 & 1  \end{bmatrix}^5$
I am stuck here,i am not able to apply a standard formula by which these matrices reduce to unit matrix.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Note that this can be written as $A^{-5} A^{10} A^{-5} = (A^{-5} A^{5}) (A^{5}A^{-5}) =I$. Look left and right before computing :-).

Comment: Moreover, the fact that the first matrix is the inverse of the second is not an accident: if $A^5 B^{10} A^5 = I$, $A$ must be invertible, and multiplying by $A^{-5}$ on both sides you get $B^{10} = A^{-10}$.  It doesn't imply $B = A^{-1}$, but that's the easiest way...